# Why do I get "No overload matches this call" error

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to make get request to some API. So for that purpose I have this method in my service

```
export interface IFilterAuctionBids {
  filterSupplierName: string;
  filterLocation: string;
  filterBidPrice: number;
  limitResultFlag: boolean;
  filterBidAwardStatus: AuctionBidFilterStatus[]
}

getAuctionBidsByGuidUsingGET(auctionGuid: any, params?: IFilterAuctionBids) {
  console.log('-', params.filterBidAwardStatus);
  return this.http.get(this._GET_AUCTION_URL + '/' + ApiPaths.auction + '/' + auctionGuid + '/bids', {params});
}
```

From my component I am sending the needed query parameteres which are optional.

```
let queryParams = {
  filterBidAwardStatus: ['Awarded']
}
this.getAuctionService
    .getAuctionBidsByGuidUsingGET(this.parametarsURL, queryParams)
    .subscribe((data) => {
...
}
```

so I want to send for example only the filterBidAwardStatus query param.

But in the service I get error

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type 'IFilterAuctionBids' is not assignable to type 'HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Type 'IFilterAuctionBids' is not assignable to type '{ [param: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        Index signature is missing in type 'IFilterAuctionBids'
```

Why is that?

I need to have type safety so when I send the query params, those query params follow the signature of my interface.

I tried with

```
getAuctionBidsByGuidUsingGET(params: GetAuctionBidsByGuidUsingGETParams, queryParams?: IFilterAuctionBids): Observable<__model.AuctionBidPojoListBaseResponse> {
    const httpParams = new HttpParams();
    console.log('queryParams', queryParams);
    Object.entries(queryParams).forEach(([key, value]) => httpParams.set(key,value.toString()));
    return this.http.get(this._GET_AUCTION_URL + '/' + ApiPaths.auction + '/' + params.auctionGuid + '/bids', {params: httpParams});
  }
```

now i have type safety but the values are not sended as query parameters

Comment: The properties are not optional in your interface (no `?`).

Comment: No, you can't just do that. If you want to send second params you need to pass first empty. You are trying to assign one type to another which doesn't make sense. Why don't you pass it as data in the params?

Comment: I tried with ? also but without success

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara it works as expected as vaira commented. Please check his answer. On his way i hgave type safety when i send the query params - and it works everything dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this error because you are trying to pass the second type of object

> { [param: string]: string | string[]; }

,
where it is expecting you to pass only string and string array, but your interface has multiple other types of number and boolean properties.
either you create a new object where every property type is of value is either string or string array or you can do it like below

```
        getAuctionBidsByGuidUsingGET(auctionGuid: any, params ? : IFilterAuctionBids) {

  const httpParams = new HttpParams(); // create 
    Object.entries(params).forEach(([key, value]) => {

        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            httpParams.set(key, value.map(val => v.toString())); // convert array: any[] into string[]
        } else {
            httpParams.set(key, value.toString());// insert keys

        }
    }); 

    return this.http.get(this._GET_AUCTION_URL + '/' + ApiPaths.auction + '/' + auctionGuid + '/bids', httpParams);
}
```

In the above code, I am just looping through your object (keys & value) of IFilterAuctionBids and assigning them to HttpPram object manually.

Comment: Can you explain the code? Does it answer the question?

Comment: @vaira Thank you for your answer ! Can you please explain why it is working on this way with Object.entries ?

Comment: Btw i accepted your answer. Thank you very much !

Comment: He created the params of type HttpParams from the params you are passing to the function which is of Type HttpParams.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara basically if she only had string and string property in her interface should not have had the error. but since she should not create a new interface just to pass in service the above method is better.

Comment: Added explanation in answer

Comment: vaira but now i see that it is not sending the values as query params - i have type safety but they are not sended as query param - why is that ?

Comment: I copy pasted everything, but it is not sending query params

Comment: I have updated the '.append' with '.set', can you make sure that it is injecting the values inside the HttpPram object
is it giving any error?

Comment: @varia yes i have value inside.

Comment: @vaira i edited my question - with your suggestion. Please take a look

Comment: When i console.log HttpParams after iteration. it is empty

Comment: two question in your question why are you passing  '{params: httpParams}', instead of httpParams directly.
after iteration, it can only be empty if prams of ur query is empty.

are you sure you are checking after iteration.

Comment: Yes i am sure. Do you send array of strings in your example ?

Comment: 'HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; } basically you are creating a object where every property is of type string or string[],
if  filterBidAwardStatus: ['Awarded'] is specially failing , you can write something like 
if(Array.isArray(value)) { value.map(c => c.toStrong())  }

Comment: updated the answer, if this does not work I am not sure what's going on.